# Force pivot item to preload before it's shown

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a Pivot with several PivotItems, one of which contains a canvas that places its items in dynamic locations (depending on the data). I get the data, and I can place the items in their place before the user can choose this item (this isn't the first pivot). However, only when I select the PivotItem, the canvas renders itself, so you can see it flicker before it's shown as it should.

Is there a way to force the canvas to render before it's shown, so everything's prepared by the time the user sees it?

My code looks something like this:

In the page.xaml.cs:

```
private async void GameCenterView_OnDataContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Load data...

    // Handle other pivots

    // This is the problem pivot
    if (ViewModel.CurrentGame.SportTypeId == 1)
    {
        _hasLineups = ViewModel.CurrentGame.HasLineups.GetValueOrDefault();
        HasFieldPositions = ViewModel.CurrentGame.HasFieldPositions.GetValueOrDefault();

        // I only add the pivot when I need it, otherwise, it won't be shown
        if (_hasLineups)
        {
            if (MainPivot.Items != null) MainPivot.Items.Add(LineupPivotItem);
        }

        if (HasFieldPositions)
        {
            // Here I place all the items in their proper place on the canvas
            ArrangeLineup(ViewModel.TeamOneLineup, TeamOneCanvas);
            ArrangeLineup(ViewModel.TeamTwoLineup, TeamTwoCanvas);
        }
    }

    // Handle other pivots
}

private void ArrangeLineup(ObservableCollection<PlayerInLineupViewModel> teamLineup, RationalCanvas canvas)
{
    if (teamLineup == null)
        return;

    foreach (var player in teamLineup)
    {
        var control = new ContentControl
        {
            Content = player,
            ContentTemplate = LinupPlayerInFieldDataTemplate
        };
        control.SetValue(RationalCanvas.RationalTopProperty, player.Player.FieldPositionLine);
        control.SetValue(RationalCanvas.RationalLeftProperty, player.Player.FieldPositionSide);

        canvas.Children.Add(control);
    }
}
```

The canvas isn't the stock canvas. I created a new canvas that displays items according to their relative position (I get the positions in a scale of 0-99).

The logic happens in the OverrideArrange method:

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
{
    if (finalSize.Height == 0 || finalSize.Width == 0)
    {
        return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
    }

    var yRatio = finalSize.Height/100.0;
    var xRatio = finalSize.Width/100.0;

    foreach (var child in Children)
    {
        var top = (double) child.GetValue(TopProperty);
        var left = (double) child.GetValue(LeftProperty);

        if (top > 0 || left > 0)
            continue;

        var rationalTop = (int) child.GetValue(RationalTopProperty);
        var rationalLeft = (int) child.GetValue(RationalLeftProperty);

        if (InvertY)
            rationalTop = 100 - rationalTop;

        if (InvertX)
            rationalLeft = 100 - rationalLeft;

        child.SetValue(TopProperty, rationalTop*yRatio);
        child.SetValue(LeftProperty, rationalLeft*xRatio);
    }

    return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several tricks you could try. For example:

1. In your `ArrangeOverride` you can short-circuit the logic if the size hasn't changed since last time you executed (and the data is the same)
2. Make sure you're listening to the events on `Pivot` that tell you to get ready for presentation - `PivotItemLoading` for example
3. You can have the control not actually be part of the `Pivot`, but instead be in the parent container (eg a `Grid`) and have it with `Opacity` of zero. Then set it to 100 when the target `PivotItem` comes into view.

Comment: It didn't work 100%, but I got it working better. I short-circuited the arrange, but I did it with a flag, and fired an event when the arrange is done. I catch the event in the pivot and hide a progress bar I've placed, then display the canvas. Thanks for the help.