# Force Pivot To Load Elements

Tags: c#, background, uwp, load, pivot

I have multiple PivotItems in a Pivot which each have a ListView. The first time I enter the PivotItem there is a small delay because the ListView is being loaded. Once the ListView elements are loaded, the delay is gone when swiping between pivots.

Is it possible to force the PivotItems to load their elements even though they have not been selected yet (i.e. load the elements in background)?

Comment: Maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30165276/2681948) will be helpful.

Comment: @Romasz I saw that before but that is different: He is trying to affect the loading of the elements inside the pivot AFTER the person has clicked on it. I am trying to load the elements BEFORE the user opens the pivotitem.